# 3D plot with additional graph in 2D plane, R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

I am looking to replicate this [reference plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRBV2.png) with my dataset "raw_new" of 50 rows and 3 columns x=resistance, y=reactance and z=frequency. If have come so far as to use plotly:

`fig <- plot_ly(raw_new, x = ~resistance, y = ~reactance, z = ~frequency)`

to get this [test plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQHA.png). To replicate the reference plot, I still need to plot the x-y and x-z 2D-scatterplots in the respective 2D planes. How would you go about this? Thanks!

Comment: plot the x and z co-ordinates with y fixed at `min(y)`, then plot the y and z co-ordinates with x fixed at `min(x)`

Comment: Thank you! I've settled on: 
`fig1 <- fig %>% add_markers(y = raw_new$resistance, z = raw_new$reactance, x = min(raw_new$frequency))`